# Get stream with empty check and feature to use orElse() and orElseThrow() for collections

Tags: java, collections, null, java-stream, option-type

`Optional.ofNullable()` checks only for `null` values and `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()` does not return a stream. Is there a way to combine both these features.
Something like this-

```
Collection.isNotEmpty(entries)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("exception"))
                .stream()
```

Instead of-

```
Optional.ofNullable(entries)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("exception"))
                .stream()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `filter()` to check that it's not empty

```
Optional.ofNullable(entries)
    .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("exception"))
    .stream()
```

Regarding your comment that you want to eliminate `null` values in the stream itself you can use this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(entries)
    .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("exception"))
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

Comment: That's a nice idea.

Comment: @Eran after looking at your answer and nullpointers I thought that there must be an easier way and in fact it seems there is :)

Comment: @Lino: This would still throw exception if I were to pass a list with just one `null` value. Eg - `List<String> sampleList = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", null, "ccc");`

Comment: Just to add, the variable `e` used in first filter is irrelevant. It can be replaced with the original list for better readability.
    `filter(e -> !entries.isEmpty())`

Comment: @FarrukhChishti This will create a null pointer exception if `entries` is `null` and also is a bit confusing

Comment: @Lino: No it won't. I have tested the scenario. 
`null` is already checked in `ofNullable()`
https://onlinegdb.com/S1tpuYGU4

Comment: @FarrukhChishti oh yeah, the `filter` will never be executed if the `Optional` is empty. But still it is in my opinion less clear in comparison to my way. A rule of thumb is that you should not reference outside variables in lambdas (if possible)

Comment: @FarrukhChishti and what do you think, is the advantage of using `filter(e -> !entries.isEmpty())`?

Comment: @Holger : It just shows that we are checking the entire list not a row entry within the list. Again, readability is subjective.

Comment: @FarrukhChishti you know that `e == entries` in this specific example?

Comment: @Lino : Yes. I am aware of that. Usually filters are preceded by streams and as a convention of sort the lambda varian `e` in this case is a row in the collection.

Comment: @FarrukhChishti no, it just shows that you are checking a possibly unrelated variable. It requires the reader to read the surrounding context, to find out that the code is not (that) broken, as `e` is identical to `entries`, which doesn’t make it easier in any way. So, if you think, it’s not clear what `e` is in this context, you should not use an `Optional` at all. Which would not be bad, as a lot of people indeed think, not using the `Optional` here and just writing `if(entries == null || entries.isEmpty()) throw new Exception("exception"); entries.stream() …` is way more readable.

Comment: @Holger: Using `filter(e -> !entries.isEmpty())` is indeed INCORRECT because variable in lambda must be final and `entries` might not be!

Answer (score 3):

For comparison, consider this:

```
if (entries == null || entries.isEmpty()) {
    throw Exception("exception");
} else {
    return entries.stream();
}
```

(Holger has mentioned pretty much the same thing in a couple comments.)

In my opinion, using `Optional` for this case isn't an improvement over a conventional if/else statement.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
Optional.ofNullable((entries == null || entries.isEmpty()) ? null : entries)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("exception"))
        .stream()
```

Comment: I would prefer: `Optional<?> optional = entries == null || entries.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(entries)`. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Eran : Explicitly checking `null` defeats the purpose of using `ofNullable()`!

Comment: Then, be consistent. Use `if(entries == null || entries.isEmpty()) throw new Exception("exception"); entries.stream() …`

Answer (score 1):

You can map to a stream as:

```
Optional.ofNullable(entries)
        .filter(a -> !a.isEmpty())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("exception"))
        // do whatever with the stream if available
```

Comment: @nullpointer : I want to check if the collection is empty as well.

Comment: @FarrukhChishti you can possibly add a filter for it then. Updated the answer